# Pre-Configured installation of applications on domain computers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, group-policy, installation, application

I have an application I would like to be installed for all computes that are joined to the domain. The thing about that is I would like to have the application pre-configured for all users. I have read up on how to do this using Group Policy Manager under Software Settings and then Software installation but no where is there a way to have the application pre-configured. 
Any incite on this topic? The only other thing I could think to do is to maybe modify the installation file to match what I want.

So let me re state what I'm asking. How do I have any computers joined to my domain get an program installed that is pre-configured. I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You really need to define "preconfigured" here.  You seem to understand how to deploy software via GPO.  Exactly what else are you trying to do?

Comment: meaning the program i want to run is a program that does voice commands and you can set custom commands and i want to set those commands.

Comment: You may have to use a different, better tool.  This is the type of thing SCCM is made for.

Comment: One could also customize the MSI if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good programs that are designed to be deployed by GPO will come with instructions for configuring them - either by customizing the MSI file, including a settings file, or with group policy templates.  Some like Adobe products  come with a tool that lets you customize almost every setting and then generate a transform file that you deploy along with the MSI.  These are the easiest to work with.

For programs that don't include such features you often have to figure out what files and registry keys need to be changed and deploy those changes through group policies as well.  Process Monitor by sysinternals will help identify which files and reg keys change.

Alternatively there are several programs available to capture all the changes made on a PC while you install and configure it, then generate a new MSI file that makes those changes on other PCs.  This is often referred to as repackaging.  Goolging for things like 'capture install' and 'msi repackaging' will bring up plenty of guides and software options.  There are pros and cons to doing it this way, so you will have to do some reasearch and see what method works best for this program in your environment.